# How to get rid of Manipulate frame?

Tags: graphics, manipulate, style, frame

Does anyone know how to get rid of the grey box in Manipulate plots? I find that they look clunky and would look much cleaner without the box, but I am very new to the software so I don't know how I would go about that. To clarify, I am talking about the box containing the plot and slider not the plot itself.

Here is my code:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks![image: this is the box I am referring to]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an option called `Paneled` to control the outer frame. Setting this option to `False` should do the trick.

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}, Paneled -> False]
```

[image: Manipulate with Panel removed]

Answer (score 8):

To remove only the outer panel keep the frame around the content area, you can use [`Style`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style.html) + [`DefaultOptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultOptions.html) as follows:

```
Style[#, DefaultOptions -> {Panel -> {Background -> White}}] & @
 Manipulate[Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {{n, 3}, 0, 10, 1}]
```

[image]